# how can I find systemcall on windows?

Tags: c, assembly, system-calls, windows-11

I'm beginner on assembly code. I never used at windows assembly code, so I really confused.

I try to catch system call when I run `printf("hello world!\n")` in windows 11, visual studio 2022. I write my whole code at last paragraph.

#### Actually I want to do is, capturing the system call which `printf()` calling during `printf()` working. That means, I want to find How c library can calling system call.

well, I do like that...

1. write `printf("hello world!\n");` completed code on VS2022.
2. make breakpoint at `printf()` line.
3. run local windows debugger with release mode, x64 architecture.
4. open disassembly window and register window on vs2022.
5. run only one line at once with press `F11`

I tried that...

1. find `syscall` function, but VS2022's disassembly can't search `syscall`.
2. find `call` function line and try to searching RAX code changes as `0x0001`(windows systemcall) , but I can't find that.
3. find RAX code changed as `0x0001`, but I find RAX code changed like `0x0001` such as `add` function.
4. find the code line that output appear on terminal, but I press `F11` key during 10 minutes. Is this correct? But, more assembly codes still remained, not finished code run.

so, I have some question...

1. Is this catching system call`s procedure correct? If It isn't, how can I trying that?
2. I tried to searching which assembly functions call system call. The answer is, `syscall` or `'call' with RAX values changes like windows system call such as '0x0001'` That means, searching `syscall` or `call` function is first, then searching RAX values. Is that true?
3. convert windows `printf()` function code to assembly code. Is output code very long? I don't understand why I try during over 10 minutes to watch output on terminal.

Thank you for reading.

```
#the whole code
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello world\n");
}
```

Comment: Note that `printf` doesn't  map to a system call, since it uses buffers. Using `write` would be more direct, and `WriteFile` even more direct.

Comment: @ikegami I really appolozied to reasking, because I heard that `printf()` are use system call, because graphic(to shown at monitor) can't access on user mode. So `printf()` must needed to system call to access kernal. Is this false infomations?

Comment: `printf` *will* eventually make a system call when it does actually flush the buffer.  (e.g. on the terminal when the string includes a newline.)  The `syscall` instruction is inside one of the DLLs, in a function eventually called by `printf`, not in that function itself.

Comment: No, libc do not invokes `syscall` directly, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`printf` is a function of libc, which does not map to any Windows syscall.

If you want use `printf` without any library, you would have to implement it by yourself.

Here is the `syscall` table for Windows: https://github.com/hfiref0x/SyscallTables

Please kindly note that Microsoft is changing the syscall id by different versions / builds of Windows. This means even you could implement a `printf` without calling Windows libraries, it is very likely only works on your local machine.

---

Edit: Since question was updated...

No, libc do not use `syscall` directly, it invokes APIs in `kernel32.dll` (and other system libraries like `user32.dll` and `kernelbase.dll`, etc.); all syscalls are eventually done in `ntdll.dll`.

This is because syscall id and calling convention of `ntdll.dll` APIs are constantly changing between different versions of Windows. In order to make the program works on other builds of Windows, libc only use APIs that are documented in Windows SDK, which are guarantee to work by Microsoft.

All syscalls / undocumented API may changes after any update without announcement, because they are not supposedly to be used in user programs. In case you are developing shell scripts, (anti-)anti-debug tools, etc., that only works in specifics version of Windows, then you could use these API directly. Otherwise you should not use them.

If you are interesting in how Windows APIs invokes `syscall`, you may debug the `Nt*` and `Rtl*` APIs in `ntdll.dll`, which actually use the `syscall` directly.You can also find some documentations about the undocumented API [here](https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/win32/ntdll/) or [reactOS](https://github.com/reactos/reactos), etc.

Comment: Thanks for notice to me. could you watching the another answer? He attaches the image link. As you explained to me, Then `syscall` can't find in debugger. But someone's find `syscall`...

Comment: @Yang No that's not true. He find the `syscall` in `ntdll`, you will be able to do so with any debugger.

Comment: Just not need to do that, you could find it with any disassembler against your `ntdll.dll`. You don't have to perform dynamic analysis to find it.

Comment: Each time when you started your process, the image loader will loads dependency for your program automatically so that they could be called by your program. So there will be all dlls included in the process memory, including `ntdll.dll`.

Comment: `ntdll.dll` and `kernel32.dll`, however, are the special one that will always get loaded by the system even if your program literally have zero dependency in your IAT. This is because Windows kernel need those DLLs to get your program loaded to the memory for execution. That's why they are always loaded, and you will always be able to find them in your process memory.

Comment: In case you are interesting in how the `libc` working with Windows system libraries, you may want to take a look of source code to the `libc` in some open source c / c++ compilers toolchains like `gcc` or `clang`. The `msvc`, however, is closed source so you will likely not be able to get the source code to it's `libc`.